# Find 'posts viewed by user' facebook graph api FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to build an algo which is quiet similar to edgerank algo of facebook. I am kind of missing 'edges' part, which is about user view anyone's post and hence creates an edge in this. Is there a way to get the posts user has viewed irrespective of user liked/commented on them. Apparently I believe this is somewhat not feasible after doing some research on graph/fql. But, did anyone of you came across anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way, via an API or any other method open to developers, to see what posts the user has or has not seen. The only thing you could go by is likes, comments, and shares. That's it.

Comment: That's what I am doing as of now, I thought there might be some way. Thanks though. :)